# Bind SSL certificate to a port number -- Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

Sorry for the limited understanding of Nginx and SSL. I have a React and Django app deployed on a server running on Nginx.

The React app is accessible using "example.org"(name is faked for demo purpose) and for the Django app, I have configured it to be accessible with port 3000 ie "example.org:3000".

The domain has SSL certificates installed and certificates are seen in "example.org" but while accessing "example.org:3000", the certificates are not available to this port.

I have been trying to allow ssl certificates to the port as well but couldnt succeed. I changed nginx conf file with `listen 3000 ssl` without success.
Please help, is there a way or should we need to modify the ssl certificates?

Nginx config at the moment is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name example.org;
        return 301 https://example.org;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.org;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/example/build;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a configuration here for `listen 3000 ssl`?

Comment: yes I tried earlier but didnt worked. I added only ```listen 3000 ssl;```  and both ```listen 443 ssl; listen 3000 ssl;```
Both didnt worked

Comment: Just to be more clear. Your Django app is up and running, using an Python AppServer and exposes Port `3000`? Is that correct? So just to test do `curl -Iv http://localhost:3000` on the machine where your Django app is running on. Am I correct? If so you will need a Proxy Configuration for your Django App.

Answer (score 0):

The Port has nothing to do with the certs OR TLS Termination in general. IN case my assumptions are correct and your Django app is exposing its port `3000` by itself you need a proxy configuration that terminates the TLS for you.

```
server {
        listen 8080 ssl;
        server_name example.org;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                .....
        }
}
```

This will terminate the TLS Session for you on Port `8080` and forwards the traffic to your Django app. There are other, more advanced options, proxying traffic to your appserver but this one will do it.

Note: In case you want to proxy the traffic through NGINX make sure Port `3000` is not exposed to the public anymore.

Comment: I tried this and some other methods as well, like changing the port to 3000 adding 2 server blocks, but couldnt get SSL in :8000 port.

Comment: You should not be able to use Port `3000` as your Django App is already running on that port. Please check if your Django app is running and what port it is using. What error do you get with the configuration posted above? In case Django is not running you will see 502 Bad Gateway.